# How can I use an LED driver (QX5252) to light up 3 different color LEDs (Green, Yellow, Purple)?

Tags: led, solar-cell, light, led-driver

I am trying to light up 6 LEDs with the common garden light circuit (2v Solar panel and 1.2V battery). The problem is that I want to light up 2 yellow LEDs, 2 green LEDs, and 2 purple LEDs simultaneously. When I connect them to the QX5252 without any resistors only the yellow ones turn on. I added resistors to balance the current and it kind of worked. All the LEDs turn on but they turn off after like 1 minute. Then I disconnect and connect the battery and they turn on for another minute. Could you please let me know how I can make this project happen?

Here is the Schematic:
[image: Circuit]

Comment: You need a much bigger battery and  PV source 6 * 20mA * 1hr = 120mAh

Comment: The battery is 1.2V and 1000 mah. When I use the QX5252 (LED driver), I can control the current that goes to the LEDs. Also, I want the LEDs to be on at night and the battery gets charged during the day with the 2V solar panel. My problem is the LEDs turning off after one minute even though the battery is fully charged.

Comment: I think your expectations are too high unless you learn how to supply all the necessary design details to analyze the fault including the design source and assumptions made.  We dont spoon feed here very often

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting too much out of the [QX5252](http://rarecomponents.com/docs/datasheets/QX5252.pdf), an NiMH battery, and a little solar cell.

You are missing a resistor.
And your inductor is too small.
You should not need more than a few mA if you use high luminous intensity LEDs.
Use only 2V red, yellow, and orange LEDs.
2 NiMH batteries in series may work better.
Pay attention to your LED forward voltages. 
Use  current mirror transistors to balance rather than resistors:  [Current distribution in parallel LED strings](http://www.ee.co.za/article/current-distribution-parallel-led-strings.html)

[image]

---

> how can I make this project happen?

First off you need to use LEDs with a very high luminous intensity.  This means you get more light with less current. Less current also gives you a lower forward voltage.

Yellow (or red) : [Vishay TLCY5800](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83178/tlcr5800.pdf)
Green (or blue): [Cree C503B](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/1300-C503B-BAS-BAN-GAS-GAN.pdf)
Purple: [Lumex SSL-LX5093VC](https://www.lumex.com/content/files/ProductAttachment/SSL-LX5093VC.pdf)

The Cree 11,000 mcd blue LED will work much better than a 2,200 mcd  purple.

Purple is very difficult to get luminosity. A 400 nm purple LED would need 773 times more photons than a 470 nm blue LED to achieve the same luminous intensity.  A 12.4 µmols of photons are required to get 1 lux from a 400 nm LED.  470 nm blue needs 0.016 µmols to generate 1 lux.

So you would be better off mixing blue (preferably 450 nm) and red (preferably 660 nm deep red) to get purple.

I created this web page that shows the conversion factors from luminous lux, to radiometric watts, and quantum (number of photons) 
[wavelength color conversion factors](http://www.growlightresearch.com/ppfd/convert.html)
The colors use the CIE factors to convert wavelength to RGB
I also made this one for Photopic Luminous Efficacy: [Relative Sensitivity Curve for the C.I.E. Standard Observer](http://www.growlightresearch.com/ppfd/lux.html)

---

If you really want it to work, use an energy harvester.

Solar cell's voltage outputs have a large range of voltage from zero to their max.  An energy harvester can work with a solar cell's output.

To make this work well with solar cells you need to use an energy harvester (like the [TI bq25570](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25570.pdf)) to charge a battery.  The bq25570 charges an Li-ion battery. A higher wattage solar cell would help.

[image]

---

> The battery is 1.2V and 1000 mah. When I use the QX5252 (LED driver),
>   I can control the current that goes to the LEDs.

You will not likely get a 1000 mAh charge in a single sunny day.

What you are not saying is the measured wattage of your solar cell at the light levels you will be using. Solar cells need a lot of irradiance to produce usable wattage.

I have some 100 watt panels that will charge those batteries.

You need to measure the voltage and current while charging the battery on sunny and overcast days.

The proper battery charging with the solar panel will be my next step.

Once you get the battery charged consider using a real boost step up regulator.  There are some that are made especially to work with a single alkaline or NiMH battery.

I would suggest you use a Low I<sub>Q</sub> Monolithic Power [MP3416](https://www.monolithicpower.com/pub/media/document/MP3416_r1.0.pdf) with 0.86V to 5.5V output step-Up converter. This regulator uses a small 3.3mH inductor and is has good efficiency for your project even when the battery is nearly discharged at 1.1V.
[image]

---

[image]

---

Even with an AAA 80% efficient step up converter and 90% efficient resistors you should still get 60 hours with a fully charged AAA NiMH and over 120 hrs with an AA.

**Discharge characteristics for an AAA NiMH.**
[image]

With a voltage source, rather than current, you will not need current balancing.  You can use a single resistor for each LED. Measure the forward voltage of each LED before calculating its resistor value.  Tweak the voltage of the converter to just above the highest forward voltage for maximum efficiency.
If the LED has a 3.1V V<sub>f</sub> and the supply is 3.3V the efficiency will be 94%. Set the supply voltage to 0.2V over the highest V<sub>f</sub>. 
[image]
Source: [Hobby Hour](https://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/ledcalc.php)

You will need to run the purple at its highest allowable current. If you use a high intensity green you can run it at about 1 mA.

> I am going to replace the yellow LEDs with white LEDs.

Very good choice.

For the white I recommend a warm/yellow white. The Cree [C513A-MSS/MSN](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/C513A-WSN-WSS-MSN-MSS-1042.pdf) has 8200 mcd.  This may seem low in comparison to the Cree 60,000 mcd green.  But this LED has a view angle of 55° and the green has 15°.

60,000 mcd @ 15° = 3225 lumens
8,000 mcd @ 55° = 5680 lumens

> Now, I am stuck in making the circuit work.

Get one LED working. Then keep adding an LED one at a time. I think using the white rater than yellow wikll give yu a much beter chance of getting the QX working.  But I still **highly** recommend the MP3416 over the QX.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. "Use only 2V red, yellow, and orange LEDs."--> I cannot eliminate the green and purple LEDs. I am going to replace the yellow LEDs with white LEDs. In this case, the Vf of all colors will be closer to each other(around 3.0 to 3.2 v). I am also going to try the current mirror circuit that you suggested. I will update you on the results. The proper battery charging with the solar panel will be my next step. Now, I am stuck in making the circuit work.

Comment: Added update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the QX5252 Datasheet the output inductance value affects the output current, the specific donor circuit board you are using is probably tuned to work with the current draw it needed.

Can you provide me with the specific circuit you are using and is it the small SIP or the DIP component you are using.

If it is the DIP the Photoresistor circuit may be getting in the way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I added the schematic diagram to my question. Please let me know if you have any other questions. I am using the small 4-pin QX5252F.

Comment: Looking at your schematic now, I would recommend an individual resistor per each LED. The problem here is the LED with the lower Forward drop is going to take all the current. As this, can you tell me what your Forward drop for each LED type is?

Comment: How many watts is the solar cell?  What is the luminous intensity (mcd) of the LEDs?

Comment: I will try individual resistor per LED and will update you. I added three resistors because I had three different colors. So I used one resistor for each color (2 LEDs). Here are the info on the LEDs: Yellow (VF:3.0-3.2v, Luminous:7k-9k), Green(VF:3.0-3.2v, Luminous:800-1000), and Purple(VF:3.0-3.4v, Luminous:200-300)

Comment: I really do not know how to choose the resistors because I have a 1.2v battery and the LED driver is using jould thief to turn on the LEDs so I don't exactly know how to add resistor to it. The data sheet says I do not need to use resistors, but it is based on using only one color LEDs.

Comment: Do me a favor, try this, since the Purple have the highest Vf, connect those directly, then put a 15 ohm inline with each of the other 4 LEDs, this will allow the Purple to control the upper limit of the voltage boost for the QX part. making an assumption that the actual delta Vf between the purples and the others is ~0.2V the 15 ohm resistor will attempt to let the each of the other LEDs draw ~13 mA. if this is starting to work but still not satisfactory for you try lower Vf LEDs on the Green and the Yellow. Let the Highest Vf LED control the voltage and current limit from there for the rest.

Comment: @misunderstood, I don't think Miti is looking for a blue LED. I think he specifically wants purple because he is trying to make some sort of Mardi Gras Device. he is also looking to keep costs down. I think the QX boost can work but we need to work out the current balance. I really just don't know how much light we will really get out of all of them. The simplest solution may be to use multiple QX devices for each of the 3 LED types.

Comment: I don't understand why the solar powered LED.  I could light up some LEDs for days on a single fully charged Li-ion 18650.   I added some more info to my answer as to why a purple LED is a poor choice.  Mixing red and blue would work much better.  Powering six LEDs would take at least a 35mW from solar cell.  So at least a 1W solar cell on a sunny day.  I've tried running LEDs using 400 watt solar panels.  Not worth it when electricity cost 10¢ a kW and a 4000 mAh battery costs $5.

Comment: Yeah actually i prefer primary cells for temporary things as well. no need in getting the whole charging thing going. There is a good video that ladyada has discussing this...

Comment: @robogeek78 I tried putting 15 ohm resistors on purple LEDs but it did not work.

Comment: So i think the biggest issue here is the QX boost circuit isn't going to boost to the needed voltage for the High Vf Diodes. if you can tell me more about your end goal I can help you in a direction that may work better for what you are trying to do.

Comment: The datasheet of a QX5252 shows 110mA high frequency output pulses with a 1.25V battery and a 33uH inductor. Maybe your battery and/or inductor is no good. I have used a 47uH inductor that brightly lights a few LEDs with 75mA pulses.

Answer (score 0):

I have many solar garden lights using the QX5252F controller IC.
Many of them use colors-changing LEDs and a series Schottky diode then filter capacitor feeding them. A few have two same-color LEDs in parallel with no diode and no series resistor.

Pin LX is connected to the LEDs so that light on the solar panel turns off battery charging and the LEDs.
4.7uH is the lowest inductor I use and the resulting high current pulses make the LEDs very bright but then a AAA Ni-MH battery cell does not light the LEDs long enough at night then an AA cell is needed.

Maybe your QX5252X turns off the LEDs after 1 minute because it is overloaded and gets too hot. Try using a 10uH inductor.